# Is it possible run a fastapi in command line?

Tags: python, fastapi

We can run any script in python doing:

python main.py

Is it possible do the same if the script was a FastApi application?

Something like:

python main.py GET /login.html

To call a GET method that returns a login.html page.

If not, how I could start a FastApi application without using Uvicorn or another webserver?

I would like can run the script only when necessary.

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual goal by having the login-method being called outside of a web context? Usually you do that by restructuring your code so that the parts you want to use both in a cli context and in a web context is independent of the views themselves.

Comment: Login was only an example not a goal.

Comment: Yes, but the question stands; what is your goal for calling the endpoint outside of the web context? It's hard to give a good answer without knowing why you want to do this; if you want to test your framework from the outside, there are test clients dedicated to that; if you want to call code in a cli context, you should move the shared code outside of the endpoint itself. If you want to do some other task, it might be better to call it from outside of FastAPI instead. It depends on what you want to achieve and why.

Answer (score 0):

[FastApi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com) is designed to allow you to BUILD APIs which can be queried using a HTTP client, not directly query those APIs yourself; however, technically I believe you could.

When you start the script you could start the FastApi app in a another process running in the background, then send a request to it.

```py
import subprocess
import threading
import requests

url = "localhost/some_path"

# launch sub process in background task while redirecting all output to /dev/null
thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: subprocess.check_output(["uvcorn", "main:app"]))
thread.start()

response = requests.get(url)

# do something with the response...

thread.join()
```

Obviously this snippet has MUCH room for improvement, for example the thread will never actually end unless something bad happens, this is just a minimal example.

This is method has the clear drawback of starting the API each time you want to run the command. A better approach would be to emulate applications such as [Docker](https://www.docker.com), in which you would start up a local server daemon which you would then ping using the command line app.

This would mean that you would have the API running for much longer in the background, but typically these APIs are fairly light and you shouldn't notice and hit to you computer's performance. This also provides the benefit of multiple users being able to run the command at the same time.

If you used the first previous method you may run into situations where user A send a GET request, starting up the server taking hold of the configured host port combo. When user B tries to run the same command just after, they will find themselves unable to start the server. and perform the request.

This will also allow you to eventually move the API to an external server with minimal effort down the line. All you would need to do is change the base url of the requests.

TLDR; Run the FastApi application as a daemon, and query the local server from the command line program instead.

Comment: Thanks, but this code make a call to Uvicorn. I asked WITHOUT use Uvicorn or another webserver.

Comment: Then no, an API is by design a web server, unless you want package all of the server logic, database connections, etc into a separate library you'd also use in the command line app, you'll need to startup the API on a webserver.